# InAppWebView desapare cuando abro otra app

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, webview-android

tengo creado una InAppWebView en mi aplicación de flutter, resulta que si abro otra aplicación como Chrome y luego vuelvo al mi app resulta que el InAppWebView a desaparecido bueno no exactamente solo que no se ve la pagina webview en si la pagina si esta cargando. Este error solo lo he probado en dispositivos Android con la versión 14.

Este es el InAppWebView que tengo creado:

```
InAppWebView(
        pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
        initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
            javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: false,
            javaScriptEnabled: true,
            transparentBackground: true,
          ),
          android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
            supportMultipleWindows: true,
            useShouldInterceptRequest: true,
            useHybridComposition: false,
          ),
      ),
        onLoadError: (InAppWebViewController a, Uri? b, int c, String d) {
          print(d);
        },
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
          url: Uri.parse(_url),
        ),
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          _controller = controller;
          setState(() {});
        },
        onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) async {
          Uri uri = await controller.getUrl() ?? Uri();
          _textCotroller.text = (uri).toString();
          _titlo = await controller.getTitle() ?? '';

          setState(() {
            this.progress = progress / 100;
          });
        },
        onTitleChanged: (controller, title) {
          setState(() {
            _titlo = title ?? '';
            cusSearchBar = Text(_titlo);
          });
        },
        onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
          _pageChangeNotifier.notifyObservers(url.toString());
          pullToRefreshController?.endRefreshing();
        },
      ),
```

Les muestro de como se ve antes y después abrir otra app y volver:
[image: Antes]
[image: Después]